# real roots of the equation $ x^x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: calculus

[1] No. of real roots of the equation $x^x = x^2$

[2] No. of real roots of the equation $\displaystyle x^x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

My Try:: for (II) Let $y = f(x) = x^x\Rightarrow \ln (y) = x\cdot \ln (x)$

Now Diff. both side w.r.to $x$

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = x^x\cdot (1+\ln x)$

Now If $\displaystyle x < \frac{1}{e},$ Then $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}<0$

and If $\displaystyle x > \frac{1}{e},$ Then $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}>0$

But I did not understand how can i trace it  and is $y=x^x$ is valid for $x<0$

plz help me

Thanks

But I did not understand how can i trace it

Comment: the second one I think it has one real root which is $x=\frac 12$ !

Comment: You found that at $1/e$ the function $f(x)=x^x$ attains its minimum value, let's call it $m=f(1/e)$. So the equation $f(x)=k$ has solutions if and only if $k\ge m$ (because $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

In [1], if we assume that $x>0$, taking logarithms on both sides gives $x\ln x=2\ln x$;

so 
either
$x=2$ or $\ln x=0$, in which case $x=1$.

In [2], you have shown that $f(x)=x^x$ has an absolute minimum at $x=\frac{1}{e}$;

so since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x=1$ by L'Hospital's Rule and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x^x=\infty$,

the equation $x^x=k$ will have two solutions for $\displaystyle \frac{1}{e^{1/e}}<k<1$,

with one solution in $(0,\frac{1}{e})$ and the other in $(\frac{1}{e},\infty)$; and only one solution for $1\le k$.

Since $(1/2)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, the equation $x^x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ has two solutions (with the second solution in $(0,\frac{1}{e})$).

Comment: In particular, $x = 1/4$.

Comment: @user7530 Thanks for pointing this out.